# How to design or create or generate a bijective ring map?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

How to design or create or generate a bijective ring map?

Comment: I don't get the question.

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: We can validate ring map whether bijective or not, but inversely thinking where does these ring map come from? How to generate them is the actual question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In generality (this is tagged "commutative algebra", so let's talk commutative rings) I wonder if there is more than taking generators of each side and writing the images as polynomials in the generators of the other side. This is a candidate for a bijection of rings, but so far isn't a homomorphism (you need to check the relations hold). In other words express each ring as a quotient of a polynomial ring, set up homomorphisms from the polynomial rings, and then show the kernels are what they should be.

Comment: It's great. Could you show an example in code of singular or macaulay. 